# Does the python type annotation take space in memory?

Tags: python, memory, type-annotation

if I'm writing this line of code in python:

```
name: str
```

Does that mean that because I did not initialize the variable `name` with value, no memory has yet been allocated for this variable?

Comment: The *information* needs to be stored somewhere (in `__annotations__`), but no string value has been stored for this variable, no.